# How to pass a long list of JVM parameters when executing a jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a long list of JVM flag values that I need to set repeatedly when executing a jar file in order to monitor the latency with each given JVM flag value combination. I know that one or two flags can be passed like this:

```
java -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but I have a long list of JV flags like:

```
-XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+ResizePLAB -XX:-ResizeOldPLAB -XX:-AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcBalancingEnabled -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:-ResizeTLAB -XX:-ZeroTLAB -XX:-FastTLABRefill -XX:+NeverActAsServerClassMachine -XX:-AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine -XX:+UseAutoGCSelectPolicy -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UsePSAdaptiveSurvivorSizePolicy -XX:-UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMinorCollection -XX:+UseAdaptiveGenerationSizePolicyAtMajorCollection -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicyWithSystemGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicyFootprintGoal -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizeDecayMajorGCCost -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:-CollectGen0First -XX:+BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs -XX:+UseGCTaskAffinity -XX:YoungPLABSize=3397 -XX:OldPLABSize=1123 -XX:GCTaskTimeStampEntries=240 -XX:TargetPLABWastePct=6 -XX:PLABWeight=75 -XX:OldPLABWeight=46 -XX:MarkStackSize=4617021 -XX:MarkStackSizeMax=713160576 -XX:RefDiscoveryPolicy=0 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=48 -XX:MaxRAM=139765086242 -XX:ErgoHeapSizeLimit=0 -XX:MaxRAMFraction=4 -XX:DefaultMaxRAMFraction=4 -XX:MinRAMFraction=2 -XX:InitialRAMFraction=61 -XX:AutoGCSelectPauseMillis=5557 -XX:AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePausePolicy=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyInitializingSteps=28 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=0 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=12 -XX:AdaptiveTimeWeight=19 -XX:PausePadding=0 -XX:PromotedPadding=3 -XX:SurvivorPadding=3 -XX:ThresholdTolerance=10 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyCollectionCostMargin=49 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeIncrement=16 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplement=104 -XX:YoungGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=9 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeIncrement=22 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplement=117 -XX:TenuredGenerationSizeSupplementDecay=2 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=13557897735059052544 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=0 -XX:MaxGCMinorPauseMillis=16119267456708329472 -XX:GCTimeRatio=73 -XX:AdaptiveSizeDecrementScaleFactor=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizeMajorGCDecayTimeScale=11 -XX:MinSurvivorRatio=1 -XX:InitialSurvivorRatio=6 -XX:BaseFootPrintEstimate=272901592 -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=2 -XX:PrefetchCopyIntervalInBytes=654 -XX:PrefetchScanIntervalInBytes=748 -XX:PrefetchFieldsAhead=1 -XX:ProcessDistributionStride=3
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It was for running with docker not local and none of the answers worked.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Stephen gave you the options in his answer. If they didn't work, you did something wrong. Unless you're claiming that Stephen gave you bad advice?